# How can i connect to a linux machine using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to this blog, I am sorry if my question is wrong.

I am using windows 7 machine and I want to write a script in selenium (using java ) where I want a xxx.json file which is in Linux machine. So i want to get that file (i.e. xxx.json  using selenium.

I would like to know how to connect to the Linux machine and how to get the .json file.

Can any one please help me out.

Comment: did connecting on local machine work ???

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver can not connect to a linux machine from windows machine. If you are using Java, It can do using `jsch` lib. Check  [this.](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

I do not understand Why you have the json file in linux machine! But If you want to read the JSON file somehow from windows - there are some workaorunds

- Using this `jsch` lib
- If possible you can move the json file to a common `ftp location` from linux machine which could be more easier for you to read the file from windows using Java.
- You can run `tomcat server` in linux machine - move the file to the server. So by making a simple `http` get request, you can get the JSON file from any machine.